# Does the equality of opposite angles not apply to spheres?

Tags: geometry

If I have two straight lines and I intersect them, then the opposite angles will always be equal. But if we draw two circles within a sphere and they intersect, due to curvature the two intersections have different defined angles right?
My guess is that they would be equal to 180 degrees and for dimensions higher the trend would continue (360 and onwards), is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is not right:

1. First of all, just to clarify, even in curvature we always have locally straight lines / planes. See picture:

[image]

2. Considering the 3D case, we can see at the two intersecting points (blue points) we have symmetric straight lines tangent to the circles. And this is true because there is a mirror symmetry given by the plane passing through the centers of the circumferences and the sphere.
   [image]

Comment: Not stupid at all. I think maybe I am misunderstanding now, but I mean more that if you choose two lines of a sphere (two different circumferences), then the angle on one side of the sphere doesn't have to be equal to the angle on the other side of the sphere, right?

Comment: @JaydenRivers I hope I answered now what did you meant to ask.

Comment: Yes thank you ! was just hard to visualise! @Puco4

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are are $on$ the sphere and they follow great circle curves, then opposite angles are equal as in plane geometry. If they are not great circle curves, like a line of latitude near the north pole, you will not have equal angles except at the exact point of intersection.